# POST call's are randomly called as GET (Symofny 2.8)

Tags: php, symfony, post, get

Error! Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: "No route found for "GET /admin/.../details/save": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)" at /.../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 180

This error is simple, a url has been triggered not via POST. The problem I have is that, this route is never called with GET.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ path('...', {'id': id}) }}">
        {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.id) }}

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="input-group col-lg-10">
                {{form_widget(form.password, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'} })}}
                {{ form_widget(form.random) }} Random
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
            {{ form_widget(form.notify) }} Notify user?
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="input-group col-lg-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="width: 33%;">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The problem continues overall in the project. Ajax call's to search are triggered with GET and I can't figure out where the error comes from. No js errors connected to this issue (checked with sentry). Any idea?

More info from emails:

```
Message:    
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: "No route found for "GET /api-v2/search": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)" at /.../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 180
Time:   
2017-06-08 17:54:31
Channel:    
request
Context:    
exception:  
{
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
    "message": "No route found for \"GET /api-v2/search\": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)",
    "code": 0,
    "file": "/.../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:180",
    "trace": [
        "{\"function\":\"onKernelRequest\",\"class\":\"Symfony\\\\Component\\\\HttpKernel\\\\EventListener\\\\RouterListener\",\"type\":\"->\",\"args\":[\"[object] (Symfony\\\\Component\\\\HttpKernel\\\\Event\\\\GetResponseEvent: {})\",\"kernel.request\",\"[object] (Symfony\\\\Component\\\\EventDispatcher\\\\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher: {})\"]}",
        "/.../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:184",
        "/.../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:46",

        ]
    }
}
Extra:  
request_ip: 
46.235.158.196
client_ip:  
46.235.158.196
session:    
[]
get:    
[]
post:   
[]
server: 
{
    "content-type": [
        ""
    ],
    "content-length": [
        ""
    ],
    "accept": [
        "*/*"
    ],
    "accept-language": [
        "en, *;q=0.7"
    ],
    "user-agent": [
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
    ],
    "host": [
        "test.com"
    ],
    "connection": [
        "Keep-Alive"
    ],
    "x-php-ob-level": [
        1
    ]
}
attr:   
[]
cookies:    
[]
files:  
[]
```

Comment: Is there a 30x redirect happening before it hits the final URL?

Comment: no there is no 30x happening

Comment: Can you show us what your network tab in browser dev console shows?

Comment: No since I can't replicate the error. I just get notified by email that this error  popped up.

Comment: I've just had a similar problem making requests to my Symfony API endpoint. I was changing route method from GET to POST.
Clearing cache helped to solve the problem.
But it doesn't mean that same action will help you.  But, you can try.

Comment: Wait, so your problem is that somewhere, somebody is using something that links to this page via GET not POST?

Comment: @MatkoĐipalo the cache is cleared with every deploy, I have the error since the beginning.

Comment: @JonStirling Yes/No
There are some bot's that are doing that. But also normal user's are using this GET url's. They are not indexed in google. I'm not generating any of this routes. And yesterday I have the same extreme situation in the admin dir.

Comment: Then, to be honest I'm not sure what help we can possibly provide. Sounds like code-wise (from what you've provided) everything works as expected. If it's your own site directing the URL with GET, then you need to find it, we can't, even more so if it's actually coming from external. The ones I see missed most often though are links in e-mails. Does your site send e-mails with links to this page?

Comment: @JonStirling I didn't post this question as long as it was just about search, since there this page is complicated. But the admin page is just the form I mentioned. All I know is that, the user filled out the form used the submit button. He ended up with an error and I ended up with my favorite erro email :) I'm out of ideas what could have happned

Comment: @MaciekKemnitz Likewise. Good luck :P

Comment: @JonStirling Thx for trying. It was at this moment that he knew he ... :D